# React Native child overflowing when inside parent with flex:1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with react native text element not adjusting parents height. I have tried to add flex tot eh cell text but that hasn't helped it jus clips the text to parents height. I would like the parent to expand to contents of the text but still flex to the cell width set of 0.7.

[image: Error]

The element styling is:

**ROW** (View) :

```
{
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'stretch',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  paddingHorizontal: 5,
  paddingVertical: 5
}
```

**CELL0** (View) :

```
{
  flex: 0.3
}
```

**CELL1** (View) :

```
{
  flex: 0.7
}
```

**CELLTEXT** (Text) :

```
{
  color: colour.blueLight,
  fontSize: 12
}
```

More images to show issue:

[image: Row]
[image: Cell]